# Talend Cloud - how to work with files for jobs published to Talend Cloud

Tags: talend

As part of our project we have developed many etl solutions through Talend, they are extensively tested across platforms which are contained to local system - meaning they were tested by manually executing through the desktop software both the free version and subscription version. Now we are targeting to push/publish the Jobs gradually to Talend Cloud. How the Talend Cloud (management console etc...) works I have a fair bit of knowledge on that but what keeps me on doubt are the file based jobs which were developed.

**Scenario:** We have few jobs which are file based - access files from FTP or push files to FTP or write data to excel/delimited files. Now we couldn't read/write data directly from files that are in FTP so we need to have local copy first. Until now as we had developed/tested on desktop software this was all good but now what I am not sure is how do we handle the situation when we publish these jobs to Talend Cloud.

More specifically how do we handle/change the file paths that were until now pointing to some random C/D/E drive but now needs to be remapped to Cloud paths - how are the Talend Cloud directories defined?

**Development Platform:** Talend Open Studio for Data Integration Version: 6.5.1

**Cloud Platform:** Talend Integration Cloud Hybrid Edition Version: 6.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Let say , If you are publishing already created job to Talend Cloud.
You can able to run that published Job on one Remote server in the Talend Cloud.
SO when pointing local directory for the FTP fetch,U have to provide remote server path.

Consider:- In existing job, you have c:/temp as local directory
similarly in the remote engine create on temp path c:/temp directory in order for your jobs to work with out any job modification.